# Why are my overflow ellipses being cut off in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image]

At certain widths, my ellipses are being cut off. [I've created a fiddle that demonstrates it](https://jsfiddle.net/eve5zebv/10/). I've tried different combinations of margin and padding, but cannot seem to eliminate it. I'm using Chrome 51.

*Note: I've simplified my example for brevity. My actual div is responsive, and the text is dynamic. I need a solution that will work for any text at any width.*

Is there any way I can get around this issue?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nowrap">This text should be truncated</div>
</div>

<div class="container two">
  <div class="nowrap">This text should be truncated</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container{
  width:196px;
  font-size:30px;
}

.container.two{
  width:193px;
}

.nowrap{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Apparently it is a bug.

Comment: If it's a bug, does someone have a link where I can follow it?

Comment: Isn't that what ellipsis does or am I missing something?

Comment: @JakobMillah The last of the 3 dots is being cut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that I created on Chromium got merged as a duplicate of [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546636), which then got merged as a duplicate of [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=610791). I will update this answer as the status changes.

UPDATE: 
The issue does NOT appear in [Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html), so a near-future release of Chrome should resolve the issue.

UPDATE 2: 
The issue has been resolved in Chrome 52.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, this is a Chrome bug, but you can easily work around it by adding some padding `padding-right: 4px`.

Answer (score -2):

For some reason that exactly `193px` this does occur, must be a but in Chrome in they way it calculates which letter to cut it off at. Use `192px`.

```css
.container {
  width:196px;
  font-size:30px;
}

.container.two {
  width:192px;
}

.nowrap{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nowrap">This text should be truncated</span>
</div>

<div class="container two">
  <div class="nowrap">This text should be truncated</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've simplified my problem for brevity, in the real world my design is responsive. I need it to work for any width. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Then I don't know that there is a solution other than just to report the bug to Chrome and wait for it to be fixed. Or do some fancy JS to make sure the width is always in increments of 4.

Comment: The text is also dynamic, and so even the increments-of-4 trick wouldn't work. Thanks anyway. I submitted a bug report to chromium, we'll see what they say.